# C# When a class instance is created to execute a method within the class

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public class TestClass
{
    private void Method1() {...}
}
```

Is it possible to execute method1 as soons as i initialize the class?
If so, How do I do it?

I didn't know how to phrase my question, so my apologies if there is already a similar question

Comment: Call it from the constructor?

Comment: Do you know what a constructor is? Although, if you're doing a lot of work in Method1 that's not a good idea...

Comment: The question is clear as soon as you know what *initializing (the correct term btw. is **instantiating**) a class* means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, from the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        // initialize here...
        // then call your method:
        Method1();
    }

    private void Method1() {...}
}
```

If this method takes a long time to execute, it is not appropriate for the constructor because the caller might not expect this. Then you should make your method `public`(with a meaningful name) and let it be called afterwards. Constructors are supposed to initialize objects not use them.

Comment: I didnt know what came over me. I forgot all about constructors. still a beginner.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So to create the class you will be using code similar to this right?

`var testClassInstance = new TestClass()`

That being the case, all you need to do is put the call to the method in the constructor of `TestClass` Like So:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(){
        Method1();
    }

    private void Method1() {...}    
}
```